# HTML Login Page

Tags: html

I am trying to create a simple login page for  a server:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Login Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<form name="loginForm" method="post" action="login.php">
<table>

<tr>
<td colspan=2><center><font size=4><b>HTML Login Page</b></font>  
</center></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Username:</td>
<td><input type="text" size=25 name="userid"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Password:</td>
<td><input type="Password" size=25 name="pwd"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td ><input type="Reset"></td>
<td><input type="submit" onclick="return check(this.form); load();" 
value="Login">
</td>
</tr>

</table>
</form>
<script language="javascript">
function check(form)
{

if(form.userid.value == "n" && form.pwd.value == "n")
{
return true;
}
else
{
alert("Error Password or Username")
return false;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The HTML above is how i would like the page to look, however i want to add another function that when the login button is pressed i would like the page to take me to a different page like google for example.

Is there anyway I can do this?

Comment: You'll want to make use of a `<form>` element, which contains a `<button type="submit">` (when the user clicks 'Login'). This form would have an `action` attribute which points to the page you want to send the data to. See the [**MDN Tutorial**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Your_first_HTML_form) for more information :)

Comment: @Obsidian Age Thank you i appreciate the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Through Html you can do something like:

```
<form action="http://google.com">
    <input type="submit" value="Go to Google">
</form>
```

Comment: The `<input>` tag does not need or use a closing slash and never has.